# Can I make the user to pay for a feature in the app using credit card or paypal in ios?

Tags: ios, paypal, payment

I just want to know if apple forces developers to make the features in the app can be bought only through Apple (which will take 30% of the income) or I can make users buy directly by using paypal or ... ? And what is the programming guide to incluse paypal or credit card in my app(swift)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**May be Not,**

There are rules and guideline made by Apple to regulate the In-App Purchase. What you are describing to make a feature available after Purchase is commonly know as In-App purchase.

Here is basic Guide line : https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/2016-06-13/

It have been specified in **Point No.11 :Purchasing and currencies**

> 2. Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to
>      purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be
>      rejected.
> 3. Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used
>      outside of the App will be rejected

Apple is very strict about the payment terms, do choose your method while, Outside payment will lead your app to rejection.
Hope this may help you to consider and go ahead with your decision.

Comment: I have not tried adding feature, but one of my app get rejected by apple nearly 5-6 times just because user user have to pay at website if he/she want to download music. i was using QR Code to get url of music track. It take me nearly 30 days to convince them and explain functionality.